# Error 3160003: Invalid table iterator

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index

Getting the **Error 3160003: Invalid table iterator** error while trying to execute:

```
 cleos push action voting.debug debug '[ 0 ]' -p user@active
```

I have a simple voting contract ([full code](https://gist.github.com/RomanFro/5a16df720632af22052445df59cda30e)) where I'm trying to print candidate by id.

Here is a chunk of code which probably doesn't work:

```
  /// @abi action
  void debug( uint64_t id ) {
    print("Hello, ", name{getcandidate(id)});
  }

  /// @abi action
  account_name getcandidate( uint64_t id ) const {
    Candidates candidates( _self, _self );
    auto element = candidates.find( id );
    return element->name;
  }
```

The struct which is stored in multi-index table *candidates*:

```
struct candidate {
  uint64_t id;
  account_name name;

  auto primary_key() const { return id; }
};
...
typedef eosio::multi_index<N(candidates), candidate> Candidates;
```

Appreciate any help and advice.
I'm using eos 1.1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your table doesn't have any elements, then it will throw this error.

Whenever you use the find command, always check afterwards that an element was found:

```
auto element = candidates.find( id );
if(element != candidates.end())
{
  return element_name;
}
```

Comment: I have this line (`/// @abi table your_table_name i64`) here: https://gist.github.com/RomanFro/5a16df720632af22052445df59cda30e#file-voting-cpp-L5.

Comment: Thank you for answer, it seems like the problem resolved. I forgot to add records to the table and the error message was invoked due to trying to access the id which is absent in the table.

Comment: Ok, I will update my answer to show that

Comment: how do I check when I'm using `.begin()` instead?  I have a declaration like this `auto matches = t.get_index<name(”myidx”)>();` after which I do this: `for (auto match = matches.begin(); match != matches.end(); match++) {` and when I run it, I get the error: ”3160003 invalid_table_iterator: Invalid table iterator”…

if I compare matches.begin() == matches.end() I get a false

Comment: @ekkis I recommend posting your own question and showing the code